# VB6 Inet control: possible to not use IE cookies?

Tags: vb6, wininet

I'm using the standard VB6 internet transfer control (Inet).

A great feature of it is that it uses IE cookies, so it is possible to authenticate into a website using IE. I can then use my app to download authenticated pages.

However, is it possible to do the opposite, to get the control to ignore any IE cookies?

Answer (score 0):

Not to my knowledge, however you could use a different HTTP stack altogether.

All windows platforms currently in support have the WinHTTP component installed.  This component is designed for lightweight server use and as a result does not use the local cache or cookie store.  IOW if you receive a Set-Cookie in a response you would need to add that cookie manually to subsequent requests if you need it otherwise the cookie is simply lost.

Open references on your VB6 project and reference "Microsoft WinHTTP Services, version 5.1".